# Convergence rate of a matrix of eigenvectors

Tags: abstract-algebra, probability-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, probability-limit-theorems, perturbation-theory

my problem is the following:

Let ∑<sub>0</sub> be a symmetric matrix and ∑ its estimator. Also define F<sub>0</sub> and its estimator F such that |∑ - ∑<sub>0</sub>|=O(T<sup>-1/2</sup>) and | F - F<sub>0</sub>|= O(N<sup>-1/2</sup>). After some manipulations that involved other matrices/processes, I get that |∑ - F<sub>0</sub>∑<sub>0</sub>F<sub>0</sub><sup>t</sup> | = O(T<sup>-1/2</sup> + N<sup>-1/2</sup>) (where I use superscript t for transpose) and also |F∑F<sup>t</sup> - F<sub>0</sub>∑<sub>0</sub>F<sub>0</sub><sup>t</sup>| = O(T<sup>-1/2</sup> + N<sup>-1/2</sup>). Now let S<sub>0</sub> be the matrix of eigenvectors associated with the r distinct positive eigenvalues of F<sub>0</sub>∑<sub>0</sub>F<sub>0</sub><sup>t</sup> an S is the matrix of eigenvectors associated with r distinct positive eigenvalues of ∑.

The convergence rate of |S-S<sub>0</sub>| is what?

I believe we have |S-S<sub>0</sub>| = O(T<sup>-1/2</sup> + N<sup>-1/2</sup>) but I couldn't prove it. I think it is necessary to use the Bauer-Fike Theorem (Theorem 7.2.2 of Golub and Van Loan 2013) but algebra is not my strongest point. Can someone please present-me a comprehensive proof of this.

Thanks.